# Is it advised to go travel?

Tags: covid-19, regulations

I have a lot of holidays I need to spend, I haven't taken any this year and the lockdown hasn't helped at all.

I was thinking to take a week off in september to do some solo travel in europe (maybe Spain, maybe Germany, maybe Croatia but not 100% sure yet).

Is it advisable for people to travel? Is there anything you can suggest before I actually book a flight/hotel somewhere?

Mostly asking as I'm not 100% sure how each country is coping with covid-19.

Comment: What research have you done up to now? There’s plenty of information about the state of each country’s Covid outbreak in the media, ranging from outbreak data eg https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/en/cases-2019-ncov-eueea to country-specific eg https://english.elpais.com/society/2020-08-07/coronavirus-crisis-in-spain-up-to-580-outbreaks-with-6900-related-cases.html . You don’t say where you’re based but most governments issue travel advice eg https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/traveladvisories/traveladvisories/spain-travel-advisory.html and https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/spain

Comment: This is probably a bit too broad and opinion-based to get any good answers. Also the situation changes nearly daily, and of course it all depends on the level of risk you are willing to take (not even mentioning the risk of catching the virus, you have the risk of your holidays being cancelled or cut short, of being stuck in quarantine or lockdown...). IMHO travelling to a different country increases the risk quite a lot in that respect. What country are you based in?

Comment: Without knowing where you are travelling from (and through) no reliable answer can be given.

Comment: I live in the UK. As you can imagine I've never been in this situation before. The answer might be opinion based, but I don't have a clue where should I get the information I need (per country) in order to decide what to do. Apart from gov.uk I think somewhat I need to look more into what each country does.

Comment: The uk site that Traveller sites is very reliable. But they too state that the situation can change very swiftly. Togeather with [Reopen-EU](https://reopen.europa.eu/en/), both can give you a good idea what to expect for the next few days. But a site, that uses a crystal ball as a source for the next 7-10 days, does not exist.

Comment: In the UK you have plenty of areas to go to without leaving the country (even the part of the UK you live) and even in most counties you will find places you have never been and things you have never done. Even when sleeping in your own bed every night you can fill a couple of weeks of being tourist, by doing the things foreign tourists would have done if they had been coming to your area.

Comment: @Willeke you're not wrong. [Mainstream media](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2020/aug/06/uk-staycation-boom-lifts-sales-of-camping-gear) are reporting on the UK boom in "*staycations*", for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think at this time it is not advisable to travel internationally 'just for fun'.

It makes much more sense to travel within your own country. As an ads campaign here reads "you are going abroad for ... you sit right next to it" where ... is a different item each time but the ones they name can be found in most countries. So find if you can find a good holiday in your own country.

Countries move from the 'do not go' list to the 'travel possible' list but also back. Requiring repatriation in some cases and going into self isolation (or worse) on return home.

International travel is possible but be sensible and only travel if you have a strong reason.
I am still planning one international trip myself but that is to meet up with my boyfriend whom I have not seen since early 2020. While I am willing to take some risks for meeting up with him, I am not willing to take those risks for going somewhere alone. And that is while I am itching to travel.